# Formula for normalising with respect to average

Tags: algebra-precalculus, average

I have a 5*5 grid (as in the figure). At each point there are 5 dishes of varying numbers of bacteria.  I'd like to write a formula which calculates the average of these 5 and then divides by the global average of all 125 dishes, ie:

$$\displaystyle C_{i}=\frac{\frac{1}{m}\sum^m_{j=1}c_{ij}}{\frac{1}{mn}\sum_i\sum_jc_{ij}}$$

where $n$ is the number of zones and $m$ is the total number of dishes in each zone.

**Is this formula correct?**

[image]

Comment: I don't think [tag:proof-strategy] is a good tag for this question. I've tried [tag:algebra-precalculus], since the questions seems to be about a relatively simple formula. And I've added [tag:average]. Of course, if anyone can think of more appropriate tags, feel free to retag the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that in $c_{ij}$ the first index tells you which point you're at ($i = 1\dots 25$) and the second index tells you which dish you're looking at ($j=1 \dots 5)$ and $m=5$ and $n=25$ then yes, your formula is correct.

Regarding your comment, there is a subtle notational issue. The $i$ on the left hand side and in the numerator is a "real" index. The $j$s and the $i$s in the denominator are all "dummy" indices - they're only there because we need something to sum over. You could call them whatever you want. If you replace the $i$s in the denominator with $k$s instead (which is much better practice) then it no longer looks like you can cancel anything.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was wondering because at first glance it looks like you could cancel the numerator and end up with $\frac{n}{\sum_i^n c_{ij}}$ and obviously that would make no sense.  Could you clarify why this wouldn't be the case? Much appreciated.

Comment: @user1134241 I edited my answer.